# Webpack different size of bundles on different computers

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using standard Angular2 CLI Webpack cofiguration.
This is the override for common webpack cofig.

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackConfigGenerator = require('./webpack.common');

let webconfig = new WebpackConfigGenerator({
  baseHref: '../../a24_/conditionviewer/',
  deployUrl: '',
  outputPath: 'a24_/conditionviewer',
  sourceMap: 'inline-source-map'
});

module.exports = webconfig.exportConfig();
```

I have strange problem that my Webpack bundle vendor.js file size is 7MB,  when I pulled the same code from git repo on different computer and run the same npm build command the file size is 37MB. 
How that is possible ?

Webpack Bundle Analyzer show that files is 15MB instead of 37MB.

Comment: npm version, check the npm and node version you are executing your builds on, i am willing to bet that the one with the 37MB is generated using node <=4 and npm version < 3. That being said, 7MB what are you using there? the entire npm registry?

Comment: I have the latest recommended version of node 6.10.3 and the latest version of the NPM 3:10:10. Both computers are on win 10. I am using Syncfusion controls in my project. Syncfusion modules are large. 7MB is ok but 37MB is terrible.

Comment: that is in weird. do me a favor on both computers delete node_modules folder. if you are using nvm make sure is the same nodejs version on both PCs in the projects folder, run `npm cache clear` and make a new npm install and then run a build. it really shouldn't be different if the system conditions are the same

Comment: On machine when bundle is smaller 7MB, node version 6.10.0 and NPM 3.10.10. NPM is globally installed in both computers. I tried couple times to remove npm package or pull whole GIT repo again. I also tried to do npm cache clear. Nothing works, bundle is still 37MB. I do all those thing on machine which reproduce large bundle, I assume that other machine is ok :)

Comment: one last test. create a shrinkwrap file (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) in both computers and make a diff between both files, check the differences.  using whatever tool you want you can even use http://www.quickdiff.com/

Comment: I did it. There are some differences in versions only. I am not sure does it have such a big influence on bundle. Here is the snippet of the differences https://ibb.co/jeGjY5

Comment: why would it have different versions? if is the same code and same system settings?. i would just do clean install on both computers, there is something we are missing here.

Comment: All differences are in the last number of version, which is nothing significant, maybe some bug fixing. As far as I understand from doc in shrinkwrap, one package always tries to get the latest dependency packages. It means that every time you do npm install, you will get latest package dependencies. Original package from package.json would be the same just dependencies can have a bit different version, and exactly that happens here, since on my second machine I installed packages couple days after on the first machine.